# RegEx to add trailing zeros to amount

Tags: regex

Is it possible to add trailing zero's to a value with regular expression.
The following figures shows what I want.

```
1
1.2
1.23
1.231
```

Expected result

```
1000
1200
1230
1231
```

Within in Java it's no issue but with RegularExpression I don't know if this is even possible. 
Please any advise.
Regards Dirk

Comment: Why do you want to use regex to do it ?

Comment: Why use a regex when multiplying by 1000 will give you the results you want?

Comment: The question depends a bit on what you mean by "regular expressions". In some kind sense regular expressions are only for matching, which means that any rewriting depends a lot on the tool used.

But, in general anything that requires arithmetic in programming will be tricky in regular expressions. However, as long as the arithmetic has a finite number of cases you can just enumerate the cases.

Comment: Within the processing of the figures I only have the possibility to use regular expressions. This is how the application is designed. I can't change that process.
The regular expression is used within "servingxml".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible only with regular expressions, as you can't generate content.

However, you can get the different digits with `(\d)\.(\d?)(\d?)(\d?)` and then display there a `0`, where its no digit in.

Answer (score 2):

The following may not be an elegant solution, but it'll work; it has been tested in Notepad++.

1. Replace `^(\d*)\.?(\d*)$` with `($1$2)0000000000`. This adds a "maximum" number of zeros to the numbers.
2. Replace `^(\d{4}).*$` with `$1`.

For the input:

```
1
1.2
1.23
1.231
```

Step 1 yields:

```
10000000000
120000000000
1230000000000
12310000000000
```

Now, step 2 yields:

```
1000
1200
1230
1231
```

Comment: Good point. However, if you input `12.34` and `1.234` this would both return `1234`. And (although this is not a requirement of the original question) this might be a problem.

Comment: @Itchy: Yeah; I'm not sure what the OP is looking for though.

Comment: This is no problem as long as the contract is clear. The contract states that the last 3 digits are fractions.